# Как поставить в ряд потомков, когда у родителя flex-direction: column?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Есть родительский flex-элемент, а внутри него 5 дочерних элементов. У родителя - `flex-direction: column`, то есть все дочерние элементы следуют сверху вниз. Но я хочу, чтобы дочерние элементы 3 и 4 были выстроены в один ряд. У одного `width: 50%` и у другого тоже. Но вот что-то не получается. Можно ли вообще так сделать?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #9e9e9e;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.parent > .child {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ff8f00;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child" style="width: 50%; flex-basis: 50%;"></div>
  <div class="child" style="width: 50%; flex-basis: 50%;"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте:

```
.parent { 
   flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.parent > .child { 
   width: 100%;
}
```

> Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #9e9e9e;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.parentTwo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: red;
}

.parent>.child {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ff8f00;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.parentTwo>.child {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ff8f00;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="parentTwo">
    <div class="child" style="width: 50%; flex-basis: 50%;"></div>
    <div class="child" style="width: 50%; flex-basis: 50%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```